# spring cloud application properties git uri

Tags: spring, git, spring-cloud

I´m setting up spring cloud with git. I have a git repository under C:\git\TestGit, which is cloned with a git respository

> https://github.com/amhg/TestGit.git

Under C:\git\TestGit, I have the .git file and README.md file

In my IDE I have added

```
> server.port=9000    
> spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${HOME}/git/TestGit
```

I run the application and tried to see the result in the browser, but I got this error

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

> Tue Dec 12 11:38:26 CET 2017 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404). Cannot clone or checkout repository:
> ${HOME}/git/TestGit
```

How it should be the spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri path?

Or what am I missing?

Project structure
[image]

Comment: Can you show your controller class ?

Comment: good question, I´m following a tutorial. The main project has two modules: room-services and config-server. In config-server I added in the application properties spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${HOME}/git/TestGit, but there is no controller in that class. only the module room-services (I have included the project structure)